# How to add loading dialog while media player is in preparing in service (Android)

Tags: java, android

I built app to play audio from internet, I use service to play audio in background, the question is how to show loding dialog while media player is in preparing posision in service(background) hire my Code.

## Activity

```
package com.uqifm.onlineradio;
.......
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b_play;
    Boolean started = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);

        b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(started){
                    started = false;
                    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
                    b_play.setText("PLAY");
                }else{
                    started = true;
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
                    b_play.setText("STOP");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
    }
}
```

## Service

```
package com.uqifm.onlineradio;
....................
public class MyService extends Service {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String stream = "http://xxxxx:36365";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Register broadcasts, Start a `ProgressDialog` before you start the service. Then wait for the broadcast. After the broadcast, hide the dialog. see example in this thread. [Send data from Service back to my activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823133/send-data-from-service-back-to-my-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Put a ProgressDialog in xml and set the visibility according to your requirement. Use interface for communicating with service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Broadcast` or try `EventBus` which is much more easier. You can post an event from the service using `EventBus` and receive the the broadcast in `MainActivity` and update the progress dialogue.
[Please follow the link.](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    fun playAudio(audioUrl: String){
    showProgressBar()
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer().apply {
        setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        setDataSource(audioUrl)
        prepareAsync() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

    }
    mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener {
        hideProgressBar()
        it.start()
    } 
    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        mediaPlayer.release()
    } 
}
```